# How to create a new list from a user's input in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop, input

I've been trying to find my way on this one and so far haven't found any answer yet. I'm trying to create a new `list` when the user is asked to `input` a string. Can i really apply `list` command here or is there a better way? Just a beginner on Python.

My program will ask how many inventories there will be (e.g. fruits, veggies, drinks).
Then it will ask the names of the inventory list.
For each name of the inventory, they will contain items for each and will ask the user to input how many items in that particular inventory.

This is my code:

```
# MODULES
import os

# FUNCTIONS


def clear():
    os.system('cls')


def skip():
    input("<Press Enter To Continue>")


def createINV():
    clear()
    invlist = []

    countinv = int(input("Enter the number of Inventories: "))

    for x in range(countinv):
                                                                                            # ADD LISTS HERE
       # print(("Enter Inventory #%d" % (x+1)), ":")

        #typeinv = input(" :")
        addinv = input("Enter Inventory #%d: " % (x+1))
        invlist.append(addinv)
        # invlist.index(x) = []                < ------ function call so i can't assign here



        for y in range(countinv):
            countitems = int(input("\nHow many items in %s: " % invlist[y]))
            for z in range(countitems):
                additem = (input("Enter item#%d for %s Inventory: " % ((z+1), invlist[y])))
                invlist.index(x).append(additem)             # <--- this is where my program stops

            #print(invlist[x])
    #for x in range(countinv)

                                                                                            # PRINT LISTS HERE

    for x in range(countinv):
        print("\n", invlist[x])

    # for x in range(countinv):
    #     print(invlist[x])


# START - Welcome
clear()
print("Hi! Welcome to Python Inventory System.")
skip()
clear()

# START - Introduction
print("This is an Inventory System where you can input any Inventories you want and how many you want.")
print("For e.g.: You can input 3 types of Inventories such as Vegetables, Fast Foods, Drinks, etc.")
print("And you can input the prices for each item.")
skip()
clear()


# COMMENCE PROGRAM
x = 0
while x != 1:
    start = input("Are you ready to Start? (Y/N):")
    if start == 'y' or start == 'Y':
        x += 1
        createINV()

    elif start == 'n' or start == 'N':
        x += 1
        clear()

    else:
        x = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you give dictionaries a try, will not disclose full code to make your program work, learn about it, it will be useful if you plan on working with data a lot.

```
inventories = dict() #initiate empty dictionary.

QTY = int(input("How many inventories? "))

for x in range(QTY): 
    name = input("Name of your inventory #{0}/{1} ".format(x+1, QTY)
    inventories[name] = dict()
```

This sample will create your initial inventories.

You can reuse this code to create items in your inventories in the same fashion.

So you will have your main dictionary act as list of other dictionaries, which in turn are a list of your stored items, with any number of attributes you want to assign to them.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I was analyzing this for a day now before i even posted it here. I was trying a a lot of things but nothing seems to work, i was going in circles. Anyways, this line here "inventories[name] = dict()", if this works, then this is the key i've been looking for. i just need a string that would iterate that i could use for assignments. Thank you, I'll send you an update as soon as this works.

Comment: it will work :-) just remember that every of your inventories is another dictionnary. and the items too as they have a name and data

Comment: Your final result will resemble something like:
inventories{
    'fruits':{
        'peaches':{'qty':2, 'price':2.99}, 
        'strawberries':{'qty':4, 'price':1.45}
    }, 
    'drinks':{
        'somedrink':{'qty':x, 'price':y}}}

Comment: that's exactly the output i want. This proves to be difficult and i probably need to do more researching in using dictionary. i was able to display my list of items (which is dict) but they all displayed for each inventories (which is list). For now maybe i need to give this a rest.

Comment: May i ask how do you assign a user's input to the first key of the dictionary? my code is 'invlist.keys[a] = additem'?   The 'a' is a count for loop and additem is a variable of user's input. It's not working, it says "dict is not callabe" Can't seem to find similar examples anywhere.

Comment: what my sample above does: it's a for loop, where we get input from the user for the qty of items, then, entering the loop you assign your input to a variable 'name'. next step, in "inventories[name] = dict()" you assign a new empty dictionary to your freshly created key.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180780/discussion-between-dave-maheux-and-geni-sama).

Comment: It's been solved! I was missing the 'set()' and the 'add()' functions. It's all i need all along. Thank you anyway. Marked your answer! :)